# I forgot the milk in the mac and cheese

Tags: cheese

Help!  I made my mac and cheese last night; the cheese sauce was not creamy, I poured it into the noodles.  This morning I realized I forgot to add the milk when heating the sauce.  Can someone help me find a fix?  Can I warm the milk and put in the casserole dish before i bake it?

please help me, i need this for guests this afternoon

Comment: What kind of mac & cheese - boxed? Scratch? Please post the full recipe!

Answer (score 3):

You can't just warm the milk and add it, but you could warm the mac and cheese mix and stir the milk in to combine. You'd want to transfer it to a bowl to do that, then back into the baking dish. You should be fine.